# Asymmetrical padding for Ionic's ion-item component on iOS

Tags: ionic-framework

Ionic's component `ion-item` has different default values for the CSS variable '--inner-padding-end' on iOS and Android.

**Padding Android**
[image: Padding Android]

**Padding iOS**
[image: Padding iOS]

On Android its symmetrical and on [iOS its asymmetrical](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/main/core/src/components/item/item.ios.scss).

Can someone please explain me the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

It is for the app to have a native touch and feel. Ionic built the default platform style for each platform (Android and iOS). If you don't like the style, you can always apply a custom css or [override](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-styles) the default style configuration.

Comment: But is there any reason for this? Does iOS native Apps really have a smaller margin on the right side? (I have no iOS to compare at the moment)